# Why am I not having any problems with the lastest versions of R and Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using the latest versions of `R` and `Rstudio` and I am doing my work exclusively on `Rstudio`. The info about my OS and `R` version:

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.0 tools_4.1.0
```

More detailed info about the `R` version:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.0                         
year           2021                        
month          05                          
day            18                          
svn rev        80317                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
nickname       Camp Pontanezen
```

In `Rstudio` when I go to *Help > Check for Updates* I get this:

[image]

Or using `versionInfo`:

```
> library(rstudioapi)
> versionInfo()[2:4] # ignoring the `$citation` which is not necessary for this question

$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.4.1103’

$release_name
[1] "Wax Begonia"
```

One of the main problems that people are having is the `ggplot2` related problems. Seems like people cannot produce `ggplot2` plots with the newest version of `R` on the newest version of `Rstudio`. But this works perfectly fine for me. For example:

```
> library(ggplot2)
> ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Why this would be the case? And should I be worried about my current projects crashing all of a sudden and being not reproducible with the future updates?

Also, I am not sure if I should use the `Preview` version of `Rstudio` or keep using the current one in terms of my projects being safe.

Comment: I am not understanding your concern about your projects being safe. If a particular version of RStudio is buggy, it doesn't affect your scripts at all. You can just reinstall RStudio to another version and you'd be fine. As an aside the preview version has an option added to change the pipe shortcut from `%>%` to `|>`, which is handy when using v4.1.0+.

Comment: @Phil when I am working on a project I always have to include the info about which version of the software I am working as it is very important for other people to be able to reproduce all of the work I am doing. So my concern everything working perfectly fine for me in these versions may not be working for other people.

Comment: @Phil also I have been enjoying `|>` on the latest versions of `R` and `Rstudio` since I updated the programs. Is my version of `Rstudio` not supposed to support this functionality? It certainly does, for me.

Comment: The RStudio IDE has no bearing on reproducibility. What matters is R itself, and any packages you call. The IDE just makes all these things run in a way that is more convenient to the user, but it doesn't materially impact the scripts themselves.

Comment: I was talking about the shortcut for the pipe (Ctrl + Shift + M). Starting with the preview version (currently v1.4.1717, but this changes often), you can set it so that the shortcut returns `|>` instead of `%>%`. The base pipe itself is tied to R since v4.1.0.

Comment: @Phil projects (books etc.) written with `Rmarkdown`/`Bookdown` using `Rstudio` will certainly have an impact on reproducibility if someone tries to go through the book and try to reproduce it without using `Rstudio`. Think of a project where one explains a collaborator in an `Rmarkdown` pdf document that "change this code, and click the `knit` button in `Rstudio`".

Comment: You can create rmarkdown documents without using RStudio, simply by using `rmarkdown::render()`. The behaviour of the "knit" button does not change based on the IDE's version.

Comment: @Phil sure :) but it was just a simple example to explain how important it is to use `Rstudio` for our reproducible projects. More complicated/realistic example would be: Using `Rstudio` `adins` (e.g. `Input LateX Math for Rstudio`)  to write the book and explain the collaborator (who is not a programmer) what to do with these addins in `Rstudio`.  And note that this person does not know how to code in `R` but needs to follow certain things to change a few things in a book using `Rstudio`.

Comment: Right but now you're getting into things (clicking on buttons, dealing with addins) that stray from the notion of reproducibility. This is past the scope of the question though - suffice to say that changing versions of the IDE does not return different output of your scripts. In fact, the most culpable to that problem is not RStudio but the difference in OSes between users' computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This problem seems to be specific to Linux and macOS.**

In [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9373) and all other reports of the bug I could find, Linux or macOS are specifically referenced. **But there is not official confirmation**, as far as I can see.

To confirm this theory then, I tested your code on my Ubuntu and Windows 10 machines: On Linux I experience the crash described in the issue. **On Windows I had no problems.**

As a further note, I experience this issue with your specific example but haven't noticed it since installing R 4.1.0 last week. Why? Because I rarely work with R scripts and the issue is apparently not affecting the Console or R Markdown (knitting or running just the chunk). Both have no problem running the example.

So I believe there is no need for you to update to the preview. For people on Unix systems, it looks a bit different. If you regularly use R scripts, you should consider the preview linked in the issue or switch to R Markdown.

Comment: I do use `R scripts` mostly, but also very often `R markdown` (+ running test codes on `R console`) and I do not experience any problems.  It seems like `Rstudio` has confirmed that this version does not yet support the latest version of `R` but this for some reason does not affect me at all (which is confusing)

Comment: From your `sessionInfo` I see that you are using Windows. So I believe this is why you are unaffected.

Comment: I see. Is it confirmed by `Rstudio` that this issue is not applicable to Windows users?

Comment: Not as far as I know. I was looking for a source but the best I could find was this issue. The total absence of a mention to Windows let's me believe that it's not an issue. Unfortunately, they do not explain why this happens on Unix systems, so it's hard to determine if why Windows users would be spared.

Comment: I made it a bit clearer in the answer. Hope this helps.